# Julia macros may treat variable and literals differently?

Tags: julia

Hi fellow Julia users,

Why does this

```
using HDF5, JLD
  s = "It would take me 48 hours to recompute this."
  filename_no_ext = "eric_demo_file"
  @save filename_no_ext
  readdir()
  @load "eric_demo_file"
```

evaluate differently from this?

```
using HDF5, JLD
  s = "It would take me 48 hours to recompute this."
  filename_no_ext = "eric_demo_file"
  @save filename_no_ext
  readdir()
  @load filename_no_ext
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Macros are very different beasts compared to functions.  One of the differences is that they do not evaluate their arguments:   http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/metaprogramming/#macro-invocation

> It is important to emphasize that macros receive their arguments as expressions, literals, or symbols.

To see the implications compare the 2 outputs (left as an exercise):

```
julia> macroexpand(:(@load filename_no_ext))

julia> macroexpand(:(@load "eric_demo_file"))
```

Comment: What's a good place to find definitions for "expression" or "symbol"? And what about some tutorials' insistence that everything in Julia is an expression? For instance: http://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/julia/

Comment: Macros are in incredibly powerful tool but are also rather complicated as they require thinking very carefully about differences between parse/compile-time and run-time.  So while it is true that everything in julia is a julia expression (making julia homoiconic) it is not true that all those expressions are evaluated at the same time